# How do I get my Python Qt app to close after using jpype in a QRunnable thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, pyside2, jpype

I'm using jpype in a QRunnable thread (using PySide2). When I try to close the app, by closing the main window, the Python script doesn't finish. I assume there are still some resources active.

The QThreadPool reports no active threads.

I've created a simple demo app. My real application requires the code in the thread to be run multiple times during its lifetime, so I can't do anything radical like shut down the JVM after the thread runs.

I'd like to know a clean way of tidying up when I want to close down.

```
import logging
import sys
import PySide2.QtCore as qtc
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw
import jpype


class Worker(qtc.QRunnable):
    def run(self):
        jpype.startJVM()
        logging.info("JVM started")


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = qtw.QWidget()
    window.show()

    thread_pool = qtc.QThreadPool()
    worker = Worker()

    logging.info("starting thread")
    thread_pool.start(worker)

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: adding a signal  in main and subscribing it in Worker class to suspend the worker thread would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
import time
import logging
import jpype
import PySide2.QtCore as qtc
import PySide2.QtWidgets as qtw


class Worker(qtc.QRunnable):
    _status = None

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.status = -1

    @property
    def status(self):
        return self._status

    @status.setter
    def status(self, value):
        self._status = value

    def run(self):
        logging.info("JVM started")
        jpype.startJVM()
        while True:
            if self.status != -1:
                # jpype.stopJVM()
                logging.info("JVM stopped")
                break
            time.sleep(1)


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = qtw.QWidget()
    window.show()

    thread_pool = qtc.QThreadPool()
    worker = Worker()
    worker.status = -1
    logging.info("starting thread")
    thread_pool.start(worker)
    status = app.exec_()
    worker.status = status
    sys.exit(status)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

> output

```
INFO:root:starting thread
INFO:root:JVM started
INFO:root:JVM stopped
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, my problem is that I need to leave the JVM running over multiple thread invocations. So, I can't shut it down every time.

Comment: i added the property setter to the exit function since you described the problem in your question in that flow. You may decouple it from exit to not invoke the thread. you may have a thread dictionary to store multiple threads with an appropriate identifier. since every worker has its own state and identity properties, you may invoke it with searching in dictionary with identity and setting the state property to false. there should be some enhancements if you consider implementing it with asyncio library

Comment: What I ended up doing was keeping a thread running for the lifetime of the app. I then only start the JVM once and use it throught the app lifetime. When it comes time to stop, shutting down the JVM caused the app to hang---but I detected the thread from the JVM and that allow the app to shut down.